# Setting sabre/dav to have root directory outside of apache web root

Tags: apache, webdav, sabredav

I am trying to set up a WebDav server using sabre/dav. I got it set up and running and as long as I serve up files form with in the web server root (like /var/www/mydocs) I can access them in read-write mode. However, when I move sabre’s root directory to be like /mnt/mydocs I can only access them in read only mode. I do not think it is file permissions because I set them up the same both places and gave apache full access to both. I think it might be apache directory access directives but I have not found any combination that works. The last thing I tried in the apache config file was something like this.

`<Directory “/mnt/mydocs”>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>`

Any ideas? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Wrong tag, change sabre to sabredav

Comment: @Wisdoom Thanks. Should be updated now.

Comment: I don't know about sabredav, but it was unlikely for you to get any response about that, now you might :)

Comment: What permissions do this new folder have? And which user owns these folders and files?

Comment: @Evert /mnt is owner and group root and permissions 755 and /mnt/mydocs is owner and group apache and permissions 777.

Comment: That's definitely open enough then. In that case I wonder if it might be due to AppArmor settings. Is that running on your machine?

Comment: When I run "sudo apparmor_status" on my system it says command not found, so I do not believe it is running. I also disabled selinux to make sure it was not that. @Evert

Comment: Aight, this is what I can tell you... if you don't have selinux or apparmor, the files are owned by the same user as PHP is running as, and the directories and files permissions all start with 7, it _should_ work. So I think one of those things is not true... Could it be the wrong user? Are you sure the username is really 'apache' for the PHP process?

Comment: Bear in mind that PHP _might_ run as a different user as apache itself, depending on configuration.